# Abstract factory query

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am facing a problem regarding abstract factory,

```
 class AbstractProductFactory{
    public:
      virtual ProductA* createProductA() = 0;
      virtual ProductB* createProductB() = 0;
 };
```

I have ConcreteProductFactory classes overriding those two member functions that create products.

I am facing an issue when I need to add a new `ProductC` creation. If I add a new virtual function `ProductC* createProductC() = 0;` then all existing ConcreteProductFactory classes need modification, which is also against open close principle.

What is the best way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why is it ok for `AbstractProductFactory` to have functions to create `ProductA` and `ProductB` but not `ProductC`, again?

Comment: it's comes latter in requirement, i can but in that case i have to modify all the concretefactory classes to override createProductC() function, one thing i have already mention, it is also against open close principle. i just want to know ideal way to handle such condn, like if we create different productB objects, later new requirement wants further more different new productB objects, in that case we don't need to create different concreteProductFactory, we can use Prototype pattern to overcome such problem. i think i have clear your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need a new interface for only those classes which need to create a `ProductC`. Have that new interface inherit from the old, modify those classes to inherit the new interface, and then implement the methods that you need on those classes. The old code won't see any difference or change.

```
class NextAbstractProductFactory: public AbstractProductFactory{
public:
  virtual ProductA* createProductA() = 0;
  virtual ProductB* createProductB() = 0;
  virtual ProductC* createProductC() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course that all concreteProductFactory needs modifications, it is the point of these factories.

Each factory creates SAME products in different way (same compare to the class you are using then).

If you dont want to do this, you dont want to use abstract factory pattern. What exactly you want to achieve?